# Postgresql "invalid end sequence"

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, phppgadmin

I've a function which adds users on my application. It does a few check, salts and hashes the password and then inserts the values. Now, when i run the function I get

```
ERROR: invalid end sequence
```

(to be honest, i get it in italian and had to do quite a job to find the corresponding english string).
Now, the single parts work very well alone, but if I put everything together in a function I get the error so I'm pretty out of ideas. Any suggestion?

Comment: Tip: To get English error messages (in your current session only) run `SET lc_messages = 'C'`.

Comment: Additional tip: When trying to figure out the origin of an error, `\set VERBOSITY verbose` in `psql` will give you more info. Also, for reverse-translating, you can just grep the `.po` files in the source code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error happens when trying to decode incorrectly encoded `base64` contents. Example:

```
=> select decode('aa', 'base64');
```

> ERROR: invalid end sequence

as opposed to:

```
=> select decode('aa==', 'base64');
```

```
 decode 
--------
 \x69
(1 row)
```

Comment: Seems like that could use a better error, like `decode(...): invalid base64 end sequence, missing padding?` I'll submit a patch. Though enabling log verbosity would provide useful context messages at least.

Comment: `\set VERBOSITY verbose`, `SELECT decode('fredd', 'base64');` emits `ERROR:  22023: invalid end sequence`, `LOCATION:  b64_decode, encode.c:327`.

Comment: ... and done. http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/53B90633.8030605@2ndquadrant.com

Comment: This can happen when you encode message and it comes out as lets say 7 symbols, and then you put it into a column that has size 6. It gets auto-truncated and you suspect nothing. But when you decode it, this error appears.

Answer (score 2):

try also

```
case 
  when char_length(sequence) in (6, 10, 14) then decode(sequence::text || '==', 'base64'::text)::character varying 
  when char_length(sequence) in (7, 11, 15) then decode(sequence::text || '=', 'base64'::text)::character varying 
  when char_length(sequence) in (8, 9, 12, 13) then decode(sequence::text, 'base64'::text)::character varying 
  else null
end AS sequence,
```

Answer (score 0):

if not sure input data correct,
　can catch the `decode()` exception, and return err value other than throw exception.

### custom function

decode with exception catch

```sql
-------- try decode, ret null if err
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION decode_null(str text, fmt text) RETURNS text AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN decode(str, fmt);
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RAISE NOTICE USING
       MESSAGE = format('--decode_null: SQLSTATE %s, MSG: %s', SQLSTATE, SQLERRM);
    RETURN NULL;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

### test

```
select decode_null('x', 'base64');
--decode_null: SQLSTATE 22023, MSG: invalid end sequence

select decode_null('_', 'base64');
--decode_null: SQLSTATE 22023, MSG: invalid symbol
```